# android + mobile printing + phonegap ? it is possible

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am developing a application in android. i want to take a print directly from my application though my mobile application itself and i don't want to use Google Cloud Printing  also. it is possible?
Printer name : Bixolon POC receipt printer
Model : SRP-257II

Comment: Can you clarify like, if you want to write a printing application or something else that prints something. Your question is not clear.

Comment: i want to develop a billing software. the generated text from my app should be print from the receipt printer.. @PrakashNadar